# How to configure Socket to be able to send datagrams via LAN and WLAN?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, udp

I wrote an C++ Windows application to send datagrams.
Transferring datagrams are via LAN works as it should.
When I switch to WLAN, no datagrams are transferred.

My understanding is, that the Windows is handling the data transmission, dependent on which connection is established. -> WiFi oder Cable.

My socket configuration is:

```
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &m_wsaData);
...
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
...
setsockopt(m_SendSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&iOptval, sizeof(iOptval));
...
bind(m_SendSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&RecvAddr, sizeof(RecvAddr));
...
```

How to configure or use other API to be able to send datagrams via LAN and WLAN?

Thank you

Comment: Use `asio` (or `boost::asio` pretty much the same) for socket data transmission instead of the C-style commands. The transmission is supposed to work for general network communication. Probably you have wrong ip address or there is some other reason your data doesn't reach. To verify if the address is correct test whether similar TCP connection works.

Comment: There is no real difference in socket coding when sending datagrams over a LAN vs a WLAN.  The code shown will work fine for BOTH scenarios. The only thing that matters is the local IP/port that you `bind()` to for receiving, and the target IP/port that you give to `sendto()` for sending. Obviously, if you want to send a datagram to a receiver on another network, there is additional routing involved (ie, port forwarding in the receiver's router, etc) but that is a hardware configuration issue handled OUTSIDE of your socket code.

Comment: Thank you. @RemyLebeau. I had the wrong IP Address. I made now a wildcard, so both IP Addresses are now available